# Props aren't getting passed down to child component

Tags: reactjs

So I'm trying to pass the state down to a Question component. For some reason the state just isn't getting passed down. I'm sure it's something obvious I'm missing but I could use another set of eyes on this one. Thanks!

```
import React from 'react';
import Question from './Question';
import firebase from 'firebase';

var questions = [{ qtext : "", options: [], id:0, answer: ""}, { qtext : "", options: [], id:1, answer: "" }];

const QuizBuilderForm = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            questions
        };
    },
    addQuestion: function(questions, id) {
        questions = this.state.questions;
        questions.push({ qtext : "", options: [], id: this.state.questions.length });
        this.setState({
            questions: questions
        });
    },
    handleSubmit: function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.state.questions);
        this.firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref('quizzes');
        this.firebaseRef.push({
        question: this.state.questions
    });
        this.refs.form.reset();
        this.setState({
            question: [{ qtext : "", options:[], id: 0, answer: ""}, {qtext: "", options:[], id: 1, answer: ""}]
        });
    },
    render: function() {
        {this.state.questions.map((question, index) => {
            <Question {...this.props} key={index} index={index} question={question} />
            console.log(question);
        }
    )};
        return (
            <form className="quiz-form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} ref="form">
                <Question />
                <button type="button" className="add-question" onClick=  {this.addQuestion} disabled={this.state.questions.length === 5}>{this.state.questions.length < 5 ? 'Add another question' : 'Question limit reached!'}</button>
                <button type="submit">Create Quiz</button>
            </form>      
        );
    }
});

export default QuizBuilderForm;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `questions = this.state.questions;` you are referencing the object, not cloning it, therefore not triggering an update on the state of the component. I usually use lodash for this part, and do `questions = _.cloneDeep(this.state.questions);`

Also your `render` doesn't look right. Try this version.

```
render: function() {
    var questions = this.state.questions.map((question, index) => {
        <Question {...this.props} key={index} index={index} question={question} />
        console.log(question);
    });

    return (
        <form className="quiz-form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} ref="form">
            {questions}
            <button type="button" className="add-question" onClick=  {this.addQuestion} disabled={this.state.questions.length === 5}>{this.state.questions.length < 5 ? 'Add another question' : 'Question limit reached!'}</button>
            <button type="submit">Create Quiz</button>
        </form>      
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! For your render method I get an error for unexpected token. It's complaining about the first '.' in `{this.state.questons.map....}`.

Comment: `var questions = this.state.questions.map((question, index) => {
          <Question {...this.props} key={index} index={index} question={question} />
          console.log(question);
         });`

just need to remove the blocks that are wrapping the entire function

Comment: @finalfreq Wow. Ok. Thanks so much.

Comment: updated the answer to fix the {} error. if it helped, don't forget to accept the answer :)